# Selenium get page after "loading" page

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

The site I parse after clicking the button (I do this by executing a method from onclick) the site shows a page with the text "loading tasks". Selenium receives only the page with the loading message, after the full page is loaded Selenium does not receive it.

```
...

driver.execute_script("filterQuestions();")

sleep(10)

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "info-button")))

print(driver.page_source)

...
```

I can't reload this page because, filters are reset when reloading